# HTML5 <video> not working in ios

Tags: html5-video

I have created a video tag using HTML5. Code is as follows :-

```
<video width="20%" preload="none" controls poster="poster.jpeg">
    <source src="source.mp4">
</video>
```

It is working fine in PC and Android devices, but it is not working in ios 5 or lower versions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Not displaying? Not autoplaying? Not playing on tap? In iOS, a video will not play until there is some user interaction.

Comment: Its just displaying a black box.

Comment: There are oddities about the `<source>` element, so start off by putting the `src` attribute right in the `video` tag. You may also have a video which is encoded in some way that makes iOS unhappy. Did you try other videos, including ones that you know work in iOS5?

Comment: Yes i have tried all types of videos but got the same result everytime.

Comment: There could be a problem with directory structures or permissions. Please try adding an `<img src='poster.jpeg'>` element and seeing if that displays. Also, try removing the `preload`, `controls` and `poster` attributes one by one.